# tailwind config and className doesn't work on my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, craco, tailwind-css

as I install tailwind and craco as the same tailwind document. but after all it doesn't make any change in my styles. ofcourse my app can recognize the tailwind classes but it doesn't make any change on my UI app.

*tailwind.config.js*

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "/public/index.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

*postcss.config.js*

```js
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
module.exports = {
  plugins: [tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.js"), require("autoprefixer")],
};
```

*craco.config.js*

```js
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
    },
  },
};
```

*package.json*

```js
{
  "name": "mensch",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^7.0.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

*styles.css*

```js
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=M+PLUS+Rounded+1c:wght@300;400;500;700;800&display=swap");

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

body,
html,
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "M PLUS Rounded 1c", sans-serif;
}
```

it's imported to my index.jsx too.

I tried several solutions on the stack overflow and git hub but it doesn't resolve my problem